# Is possible explicitly check for permissions inside a onRequestPermissionsResult?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm making an Android App that adds a map to a activity, the user can center the map with their current location using the "location layer". to add the location button in the map with:

```
 mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

I'm checking for the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission inside `onMapReady` method and everything works fine, but I need finish the activiy and re-open it to see the changes (the location button).

So, I'm using `onRequestPermissionsResult` to check the user response, but when I call `mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true` Android Studio says:

> Call requires permisson which may be rejected by user: code shoud
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potencial SecurityException...

This is my code:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    mMap.uiSettings.isCompassEnabled = true

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),SOLICITA_UBICACION_CLAVE)
    }else{
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    }

    mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled  = true
    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId){
        android.R.id.home -> {
            onBackPressed()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when(requestCode){
        SOLICITA_UBICACION_CLAVE -> {
            if((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity,"Permiso garantizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false
                Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity,"Permiso denegado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, How can I call `mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true` inside `onRequestPermissionsResult`?,

What's the purpose to check a permission inside `when` instruction for the request code if is supposed that is currently granted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, How can I call mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true inside onRequestPermissionsResult?,

Do it the way that you are, and add the appropriate `@SuppressLint` annotation to suppress the warning. There should be a quick-fix for this in Android Studio that will add`@SuppressLint` with the right property.

Presumably, there is some bug or limitation in the Lint rule that is causing your problem. For example, this is a relatively old Lint check, and so perhaps it is not handling all Kotlin scenarios correctly.